# How to Import Angular Chart in IONIC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, chart.js

I need to work with angular-chart, when I import :

```
<script src="lib/Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<link href="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And inject chart.js in my app.js:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';  
    angular.module('App', []);
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'App','ngCordova', 'chart.js']).run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

            //...
        });
    });
})();
```

I have #problem :

```
angular-chart.min.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ angular-chart.min.js:13(anonymous function) @ angular-chart.min.js:13
ionic.bundle.js:13380 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module chart.js due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'chart.js' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=chart.js
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15270:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15194:38)
    at module (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15268:14)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17674:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17675:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=chart.js&p1=Error%3…%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17658%3A5)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17697:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17675:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17584:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14942:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14963:12)
```

If I import angular.min.js #problem is solved

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But It appears a warning in browser console:

```
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

How can I solve ?

Comment: Ionic tends to do the warning sometimes when you have other renditions of Angular. I would honestly just ignore it,

Comment: Could u add to the question all the js you are including in your application in the order you are calling them?

Comment: I use same of <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/master/dist/angular-chart.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/master/dist/angular-chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: where are you loading the scripts for the ionic libraries? ionic should be loading angular.  It seems like you have these scripts separate from your ionic scripts, and they are loading before ionic.  Without a reference to angular, the other two fail, and with a reference to ionic, the ionic script bombs because it tries to load angular a second time later in the process.

Comment: Try to load script files at the end of the body.

Answer (score 1):

i have a  link that give charts as per your demand with low effort.https://live.amcharts.com/new/
you can even create 3D charts also, you can use it in ionic as well as normal angular web application

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the way you loading the css and js files. If you are using the same code:

```
    <script src="lib/Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

try:

```
<link href="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

This may help you.